# How do I remove the "null" word when I append characters to a String?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to print the HTML page source of a website. I initialized the String as null in line 45. However, when I try to print the newly appended string the null keyword is displayed.

I tried removing the initialization of String.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public class ToPrintWebSiteSource extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    @Override
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            siteUrl = new URL(urls[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl.openConnection();
            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while(data!= -1){
                char character = (char) data;
                result += character;
                data = reader.read();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Error:","The code is not working....");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  result;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String result = null;
    ToPrintWebSiteSource helloWorld = new ToPrintWebSiteSource();
    try {
        result = helloWorld.execute("https://web.ics.purdue.edu/~gchopra/class/public/pages/webdesign/05_simple.html").get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Page Source Html:", result);
    }
   }
```

The result I received was:

```
null<html>

<head>
<title>A very simple webpage</title>
<basefont size=4>
</head>
```

Comment: `String result = ""; //  set it to empty string.`

Answer (score 3):

You should set it to an empty string and not null. When you concatenate a string with `null`, the string "null" gets added to it, rather than being empty.

Better yet, you shouldn't even be using string concatenation here. This is what a `StringBuilder` is for.

```
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    char buffer[] = new char[100];

    try {
        siteUrl = new URL(urls[0]);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl.openConnection();
        InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        for (int n; (n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
            result.append(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Error:","The code is not working....");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.toString();
```

This reads multiple chars at a time into a char array, appending the characters to the `StringBuilder` until all the data is read. Setting the size of the array to 100 was arbitrary, you can make it larger if you want to read more data at a time.